# Is it possible to delay a style property using jQuery?

Tags: jquery

This is my code:

```
<img class="animated fadeIn" src="https://example.com/img/image.png" style="background-image: url('.$this->url.'/thumb.php?src='.$row['background'].'&t=b&w=800&h=300&q=100)" />
```

I need to load the style property after the page is loaded.

Is it possible using jQuery?

Comment: Yes, jQuery makes that very simple, but your `<img>` element will need some distinguishing property, eg an id, that will allow it to be selected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would change the html to use data-attributes

```
<img class="animated fadeIn" src="https://example.com/img/image.png" data-style="background-image: url('.$this->url.'/thumb.php?src='.$row['background'].'&t=b&w=800&h=300&q=100)" />
```

and then apply it to the actual style when you want (*using the `load` event or a timeout*)

```
$(window).on('load', function(){
   $('[data-style]').attr('style', function(){ return $(this).data('style'); });
});
```

This way the code will apply to as many elements you want

---

The timeout version would be like this

```
$(window).on('load', function(){
   setTimeout(function(){
       $('[data-style]').attr('style', function(){ return $(this).data('style'); });
   }, 5000); // apply the style 5 seconds after the page is loaded.
});
```

Comment: ok I tried on document ready function and it works as expected, thanks

Answer (score 1):

Search for jQuery's `ready()` event, and use `attr('style', 'your_inline_style')` to set the CSS within the event.

Comment: The point appears to be to apply the style on *page loaded* not *document ready*, which is likely to be too early.

Answer (score 1):

You could try using an ID for your element:

```
<img id = "something" class="animated fadeIn" src="https://example.com/img/image.png" ...
```

And then do the jquery on that ID, after the page is ready:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#something").css('background-image', 'whatever-you-are-linking-to');
});
```

Comment: The point appears to be to apply the style on *page loaded* not *document ready*, which is likely to be too early.

Answer (score 0):

Run this while the page is loading. It will remove the style and then replace it once the image has fully loaded.

```
(function(){
    var img = $("img.animated.fadein")[0];
    var style = img.style;
    img.style = "";
    img.onload = function(){ this.style = style; };
})()
```